# Need help to interpret sampling numbers

Tags: sampling

This question was flagged as offtopic, but I am sorry, this is NOT a question which "focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations, or it asks about obtaining datasets".

This is the question about the very essence of statistical quality control.

Again: I got stuck on a simple application of ISO 2859 and Dodge-Romig and other sampling tables. Let's take a simple example of sampling according to ISO 2859 as featured on [www.sqconline.com](http://www.sqconline.com) - I am trying to use a calculator to determine the sampling plan and enter the batch size 3201 to 10000, AQL=10%, Inspection Level = II, Normal inspection.

The calculator gives me the following values for Single Sampling Plan:

The Single sampling procedure is:
Sample 125* items.
If the number of non-conforming items is
21 or less --> accept the lot.
22 or more --> reject the lot.

NOW, I am sorry but 21 per 125 is 0.168, which is 16.8%.

How is this possible that by making sure that there are no more than 21 defects on the sample of 125 items, which is making sure that the sample average error rate is not worse than 16.8%, I am ensuring that AQL does not exceed 10%?

The simple logic says that if I want to get low AQL my sample should be BETTER than AQL on the population, not worse.

I would be extremely grateful for any explanation of this "paradox".

Comment: The issue you have raised as a concern is certainly correct --- you should not trust that test logic.  Can you please specify where this calculator is that you used?

Comment: This question had been flagged as offtopic, but I would say that it's ontopic because it is about a statistical calculation. A problem with the question is that more information could be provided about the ISO 2859 specifications and about the calculator that has been used.

Comment: Ben, the calculator is SQConline: www.sqconline.com